# how to change border screen color in tasm?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

i need to set the blue border screen color and display a graphic dot in the center of the screen in tasm. But i really don't uderstand what i'm doing wrong for displaying border screen color.
For changing border color, in my task there's requirement to use instruction int 10: function code 1001h.

i tried this:

```
.model small
.code
org 100h

start:
    ;using 320x200 256 color graphics
    mov ax, 13h 
    int 10h

    ;changing screen color
    mov ax, 1001h           
    mov bx, 0001h    
    int 10h
    
    ;draw pixel
    mov ax, 0C01h      
    mov bh, 00h  
    mov cx, 160         
    mov dx, 100               
    int 10h

    
    mov ax, 4C00h       
    int 21h
end start
```

This is the result of this program:
[image]

Comment: I don't believe that DosBox supports emulating the overscan feature of CRT displays using int 10h/AX=1001h.

Comment: oh, is it just impossible in dosbox? Or it's because of my dosbox screen settings?

Comment: It isn't possible to do in DoxBox, unless the feature is added in the future. You could draw your own border but that border would be inside the viewable area.

Comment: i see, thank you for explanation \( ' ^')/

Comment: Works in DosBox-X and You should set value in `bh` not `bl`. `mov ax, 1001h`, `mov bx, 0100h`, `int 10h`. `Output = surface`, `Overscan = 1 - 10`.